# ES6 imports - what does the exclamation mark mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jspm, systemjs

I'm following along with the [Choose ES6 Modules Today](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/choose-es6-modules-today/) guide, and I noticed one of the import statements he's using has an exclamation mark at the end:

`import 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!';`

What does that exclamation mark signify?

This import statement appears on the first line of the [startup.js](https://github.com/codylindley/jspm-startup/blob/master/src/startup.js) file.

Comment: im guessing that means don't execute as javascript.

Comment: Please note that neither the module loader nor how it should interpret module identifiers are specified in the standard. This is all specific to the module loader you are using (e.g. systemjs) not ECMAScript.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It means that a plugin will be called to load the file. By default the plugin/loader name equals the extension name. So in your example the [css plugin](https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-css) will be called to load the `bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css` file. One can define the plugin explicitly:

```
import 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!css';
```

or

```
import 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css!customCssLoader';
```

Plugins have to be installed like any other normal module. More about this syntax [here](https://60devs.com/differences-in-plugin-micro-syntax-between-various-es6-loaders.html).