# What does !(exclamation point) mean before and after in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with this project and am trying to figure out what the exclamation before and after means.

```
import ICHING from '!json!constants/iching_deoxy.json';
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620018/es6-imports-what-does-the-exclamation-mark-mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an [inline `webpack` loader](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#inline) indicator where `json` is the `json-loader`

> It's possible to overwrite any loaders in the configuration by
>   prefixing the entire rule with !

This is not part of the Javascript or Ecmascript specifications